# OpenVPN: Is there a way to encrypt the file that contains the username/password in order to pass it as an argument to auth-user-pass?

Tags: linux, password-encryption, openvpn

I want to pass a file that contains username/password via the **auth-user-pass** argument & I want to have it encrypted for security reasons

```
openvpn ..... --auth-user-pass credentials.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily, I have written the following script. 
**Credentials.txt** is base64 encoded. It is decoded in a temp file & it is passed as an argument to openvpn.
You can modify your script accordingly for encryption/decryption functionalities.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Ensure TEMP file is deleted after execution of the script.
# If script is terminated
trap 'rm -f "$TEMP_FILE"' EXIT
# If script is interrupted
trap 'rm -f "$TEMP_FILE"' INT

# Create TEMP file & if fails exit
TEMP_FILE=$(mktemp)|| exit 1

# Decode credentials & write to the TEMP file
base64 -d credentials.txt > $TEMP_FILE

# Connect to VPN
sudo openvpn --config personal-config.ovpn --auth-user-pass $TEMP_FILE
```

Comment: base64 is not an encryption. Just by looking at the file will be immediately obvious that it was base64 encoded and can just as easily be reverted

Comment: I agree with Aethalides. Also, since I don't think your script would terminate until openvpn did, the temporary file would remain in a plaintext file as long as the interface was up, which obviates any potential advantage over a plaintext username/password file. In fact, it could be even less secure than a file protected with user or group read permissions, depending on the your default umask. However, I think that your script could be modified to fix both of these issues.

Comment: @Aethalides
The comment clearly says that I am using a base64 encoding as a temporary solution.
As I need to use OpenVPN many times per day, I find it pretty handy.
Security is an issue, but is way safer than storing your credentials in a network manager (e.g. Gnome).

Comment: @CaseyJones 
The temp file is deleted after the process is terminated.

Comment: Yes, I do see that the temp file is deleted after your shell script terminates. However, that only happens after killing OpenVPN and disconnecting from the VPN. So for the entire duration of the connection, the plaintext password remains available in a temp file.